# Spring Boot Preprocess JSON data

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, serialization

I have a RESTful Spring Boot API, that has a registration end point.

Inside my `@RestController` class I have written a simple String value pre-processor, to trim and replace whitespace only strings with `null` values.

```
  @InitBinder
  public void blankStringBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("password", "confirmPassword");
    StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmerEditor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerEditor);
  }
```

But when I submit the data from Postman as raw `JSON`, the trimming edit is not taking place. I put a break point inside `blankStringBinder` method and I see that it gets called on each incoming request.

The `WebDataBinder` seems to work for `form-data`. Is there a way to make it work for raw `JSON` data too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do this only on few `String` fields, first create a custom `JsonDeserializer`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

public class EmptyToNullCustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
        if (node.textValue().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return node.textValue();
    }
}
```

Then add this annotation on each `String` of the POJO: `@JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyToNullCustomDeserializer.class)`.
For example :

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyToNullCustomDeserializer.class)
private String content;
```

---

**Edit:**

If you have got a lot of `String` fields you want to pre-process, annotating each field can be really cumbersome.

As an alternative you can have **all** `String` fields pre-processed, without having to annotate them at all. For this you have to first modify `EmptyToNullCustomDeserializer` so that its parent class is Jacksons `StdDeserializer`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EmptyToNullCustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {
    protected EmptyToNullCustomDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
        if (node.textValue().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return node.textValue();
    }
}
```

And then create this component in order to customize the Jackson object mappers by adding the above deserializer to the configuration:

```
import java.util.List;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private EmptyToNullCustomDeserializer emptyToNullCustomDeserializer;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder(List<Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer> customizers) {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        for (Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer : customizers) {
            customizer.customize(builder);
        }
        return builder;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addEmptyToNullStringDeserialization() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
                jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializerByType(String.class, emptyToNullCustomDeserializer);
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiny extension to the *[excellent answer from @sébastien-temprado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003246/265954)*: if you need to "trim blank string to null" (as the question was asked) instead of "trim empty string to null", use e.g. Apache Commons Lang `StringUtils`:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

//[...]
@Override
public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
    
    return StringUtils.trimToNull(node.textValue());
}
//[...]
```